# Polyconic projection using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, projection, matplotlib-basemap

Is there a way to draw points on a sphere with a polyconic projection using Matplotlib? (like this map http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyconicProjection.html)
I tried to use `mpl_toolkits.Basemap` but the code seems not work very well with

```
m = Basemap(llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat=90,
            llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180,
            resolution='l', area_thresh=100., projection='poly',
            lat_0=0., lon_0=0.
            )
```

(I get `GEOS_ERROR: b'TopologyException`)

Comment: Maybe this example from basemap documentation is useful: http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/poly.html

Comment: Yeah, but I keep getting the error I mention in my post